# How To Create a Popup Window from Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using the following to attempt to create a popup in IE 9

```
function popUp(url) {
  day = new Date();
  id = day.getTime();
  eval("page" + id + " = window.open(url,'" + id + "','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=600,height=520,left = 400,top = 200');");
  return false;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari - but IE 9 refuses to open a popup - instead opening the url in a new tab. I've disabled the popup blocker in IE9 - but the function above still opens the url in a new tab and not in a popup.

Any suggestions on how to get IE9 to 'popup'?

Comment: http://www.ghacks.net/2010/10/03/internet-explorer-9-tabbed-browsing-settings/ says that it's a user option in IE9 whether popups open in a window or in a tab.  There's probably no way to override what the user has set and there shouldn't be anyway, because there's no better way of alienating your users than forcing browser behaviours they don't want on them.  FYI, Firefox also has the option of opening popups in a new tab.

Comment: Indeed - that's where it was - under the General Tab for Internet Options - for Tab settings - 'When a pop-up is encountered:' - there are options to create a popup window or a tab.

Answer (score 3):

This code seems to work in IE9 (just checked - opens a new window, not a tab):

```
function popUp(url) {
  day = new Date();
  id = day.getTime();
  eval("page" + id + " = window.open(url,'" + id + "','_blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=600,height=520,left = 400,top = 200');");
  return false;
}
```

I think it may have something to do with indicating the window name, which is different from the existing window.

Comment: Thanks for the test. I've tried your function above and it is still dependent on Internet Explorer tab settings. Internet Options > Tabs > Settings > 'Let Internet Explorer decide how pop-ups should be open', or 'Always open pop-ups in a new window' will work with either function. If 'Always open pop-ups in a new tab' is set - then  nothing will force a new window to open.

Comment: I suppose, if the user explicitly set "always open in new tab", you don't have any way of overriding it.  After all, javascript is client-side and the client has control over what's allowed and what's not.

Answer (score 3):

when the user has 'Let Internet Explorer decide how pop-ups should be open' which is the default, setting resize=yes will make IE9 open a tab and resize=no will allow the popup. this might be the same with other attributes i haven't tested.