# How to get default left and right arrow in IE9 using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and want to open a new window using JavaScript.

I have used the below code:

```
var parameters = "toolbar=yes,menubar=no";
var ptr = window.open('NZFReferenceSelector.aspx?RefID=' + refID, '_self', parameters, false);
if(ptr) 
    ptr.focus();
return false;
```

It works well in IE7 but in IE9, the pop up window is opened behind the parent window and it did not show the arrows on top. However, it shows tool bar with `*` icon only.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you provide images? It is hard to diagnose given your description. Alternatively, I have had no trouble using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464980/how-to-create-a-popup-window-from-internet-explorer-9 and I just tested it on the latest build of IE9, and IE10, and it performs as I expect.

Comment: how to upload image to this site

Comment: I am not sure if you have enough reputations to upload images. But in case you don't have, then just upload the image at [imageshack](http://imageshack.us/) or any other image uploading site and give the link here. Also try following the post @wcdolphin has mentioned, you might not need to wait for any answers